# How can combobox event handler fire after the item drops down?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I am firing a function my_function when the combobox index is selected and it runs depending on the selected combobox selected index.(Using C# code for this in WinForms and WPF)

Here how I declare the event handler:

```
ComboBox1.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectionChanged);
```

The event handler of the combobox:

```
 private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         my_function();
        }
```

And my_function:

```
private void my_function(){

if(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
//do something

else{
//do something else
}
}
```

Now my problem is when I click on the combobox, the program starts executing the code before the combobox item drops down. So it looks like the combobox stucks dropping down before it actually drops down after few seconds. Is it possible first the combobox item drops down and then my_function executes?

Comment: How is it both winforms and wpf?

Comment: I use WinForms and in WPF I use code not binding.

Comment: First, add the correct tag to your question. Please specify whether it is Winforms or WPF. You said you use Winforms, but "SelectionChanged" is a WPF event. In Winforms, you should use "ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event". In addition, what does "in WPF I use code not binding" mean?

Comment: I mean I use WPF as WinForms not using databinding but same issue happens in WinForms as well. My problem is when I click on the combobox the my_method fires and comboboxt item list stucks until my_method stops running. But I need it to fire after combobox is settled(after the item drops down), I hope more clear.

Comment: It seems that [SelectionChangeCommitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted?view=net-5.0) can be used with WinForms. Similarly, SelectionIndexChanged and SelectionValueChanged may be used. [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=net-5.0#events) In WPF, it seems to be around this article. [Trying to use the combobox selectionchangecommitted event.](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5216458/Trying-to-use-the-combobox-selectionchangecommitte)

Answer (score 0):

Using the event `SelectionChangeCommitted` instance of `SelectionChanged` will fire your function when committing your select